# PHPexcel formula error for complex formula

Tags: excel-formula, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to read an excel sheet. This is my code.

```
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$data = $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

But I'm getting this error message.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with
message 'Individual client details!E4 -> Formula Error: An unexpected
error occured' in

/var/www/html/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Cell.php:300 Stack
trace: #0

/var/www/html/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(2458):
PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() #1

/var/www/html/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(2534):
PHPExcel_Worksheet->rangeToArray('A1:F54', NULL, true, true, true) #2

/var/www/html/application/libraries/Excel.php(51):
PHPExcel_Worksheet->toArray(NULL, true, true, true) #3

/var/www/html/application/controllers/broker.php(116): Excel->read(1,
true) #4 [internal function]: broker->upload_debtors_info() #5

/var/www/html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(339):
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6 

/var/www/html/index.php(192):
require_once('/var/www/html/s...') #7 

{main} thrown in
/var/www/html/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 300
```

It appears to be this formula makes the error.

```
=Table1[[#This Row],[Outstanding Debtor Balance Over T+3 (Rs.)
  '[A']]]-Table1[[#This Row],[Portfolio Value (Rs.) 
  '[B']]]
```

But I'm not sure how to fix. Thanks if someone can solve it.

Comment: Switch to using PHPSpreadsheet instead of PHPExcel. PHPExcel hasn't been updated in years, is no longer supported and has been archived.

Comment: You are totally correct but unfortunately I can't do that since a PHP version issue which brakes my total software :'(

Comment: If you're using a PHP version that old you seriously need to think about/consider moving to a recent version to avoid issues in general. Most "breakage" isn't too difficult to correct to use the current version of PHP.